# migration of ionic cordova to capacitor in ionic angular

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have one application, and due to a recent upgrade to the Android SDK, I cannot publish fresh builds to Google Console. I'm using ionic, angular, and Cordova.

```yaml
**ionic info**

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 9.6.5
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Adding `package.json` file

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/image-picker": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-launcher": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic-native/market": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/network-interface": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "com.razorpay.cordova": "git+https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.3",
    "cordova-ios": "6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin-fixed": "^1.2.1",
    "firebase": "7.24.0",
    "flickity": "^3.0.0",
    "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^11.0.3",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^2.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "x2js": "^3.2.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "cordova-android": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-clipboard": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-launcher": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "^1.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-networkinterface": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-photoeditorsdk": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-networkinterface": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROIDX_VERSION": "1.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
        "ANDROID_FCM_VERSION": "21.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_BOM_VERSION": "26.0.0",
        "ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.4",
        "ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "4.1.0"
      },
```

###### What I've Tried:

1. upgraded ionic version to 6 got peer dependency error
2. upgraded Cordova version to 12 and got peer dependency error
3. added ionic capacitor in existing code getting error

   [image]

###### Workaround:

I have added a `google-package.json` file in the app folder still the same error

**Should I keep ionic cordova? or migrate it to a capacitor ?**

Comment: Did you follow the migration guide? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor

Comment: Yes. i'm following the migration guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. revise your package.json file.
2. write down list of cordova plugins and find Capacitor alternatives.
3. Update Angular and its libs
4. Update Ionic (this is important to do this at THIS step).
5. Take a long time to refactor ALL your code that uses cordova Plugins to Capacitor plugins.

And follow the migration guide if you get stuck: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is it necessary to use Capacitor plugins, or can we still use Cordova plugins in Capacitor? This is my first time migrating, so I apologize for any dumb questions.

Comment: You can still use cordova in capacitor, but i would suggest to update the plugins to Capacitor because many reason. Maybe some of the Cordova plugins you are using does not have a capacitor alternative and capacitor may not support it, that's why i said do step 2,  figure out what can stay and what needs to change, then go from there.

Comment: Thank you; following this, I have partially succeeded; I will let you know if I become stuck in the middle.